# GTA Online - Calling Another Player In-Game

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Yesterday, I was in a party with a couple friends and I noticed I could go into my contacts and give them a call. I tried multiple times and each time...nothing happened. My friend never received the call and I never received theirs; the phone just kept ringing. Each time you call someone, it takes $10 from your bank account (for some reason).

According to the [GTA Online Guide - Your Phone Is Your Friend](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/tutorials/your_phone/your_phone_is_your_friend/):

> You can also make player-to-player phone calls using your phone – navigate to the Gamertag / PSN ID of one of your friends and select ‘Call.’ This will even work if they are in Story Mode.

That's nice and all, but it still doesn't explain what happens when you call another player.  Does anyone know what is supposed to happen when you call someone in-game? I even checked to see if any private chats or parties are created, but nothing happens! The phone just endlessly rings.

---

***Edit: (2 Days Later)***

Well it's been two days and I still have no idea what this feature does and, after reading some of the comments, I decided to update my question.

Here is my current situation:

I am playing on a Xbox 360 and I am trying to "Call" other players (an option that is located in your phone's contacts).

I have tried this many times with many people while I was:

- In a party
- In a private chat
- In-game chat (no party/chat)

Each time I tried calling another player (who also has a Xbox 360 since the game is not cross-platform), the person I was calling never received the call and never got a notification that I was even calling them.  However, every time I was charged $10. I would let the phone ring for several minutes at a time with no response.

***Question:***
What is the point of this feature and why does it cost $10? For example, you can call Lester and he can locate a car for $100.  Since I am being charge $10 for each call made to another player, I am expecting something to occur (i.e. the person you are calling answers the phone and immediately spawns near you). I'm *not concerned* with what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: Are you attempting to call a friend on a different platform? Are you asking the underside of what is going on? I mean ` explain what happens when you call another player` isn't something thats easily diagnosable. Are you sure your friend is receiving the call? Are you attempting to call people and not getting any answers?

Comment: @ColeBusby I updated my question. Also GTA Online is not cross-platform.

Answer (score 6):

The point of the feature is to enable one to one voice calls from inside the game(I have succesfully used this feature to talk with friends). It doesn't matter if you're in SP or MP. The reason why it costs 10$ is to add immersion and to act as a yet another money sink in GTA online.

Comment: Thank you! I have been searching online for some sort of answer!

Comment: Please mark this answer as right, if you feel that I answered your question :)

Comment: I've been through GTA sites on the net and can't find any official documentation on the phone, figures... I'll check the actual paper manual when I get home.

Comment: Don't worry, I am going to wait another day for any more answers, then you will get the accept and bounty.

Comment: looks like the official manual just contains a link: go get your manual from here: http://www.rockstargames.com/V/info/manual

Comment: Went through the manual app, no info even there. So no official documentation on how the phone should work...

Comment: today I saw an online notification when signing onto GTA Online that said exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that as your friends get migrated to your phone's contact list, It sets up a VoIP server to connect you to your friend similar to skype. A Co-worker of mine has the game and was explaining the situation you described. I feel that in order for you to make a call (like you would in real life) You must pay the cell phone company for your phone call. (Just an added twist for continued immersion)

He was saying it is similar to private chat but as I do not own the game I cannot verify. I know that Xbox Players can make a private chat between two people and it is along the same mechanics, but they can also do party chat using the Xbox Live services, It would make sense that Rockstar included that API into their game to allow this capability without breaking immersion.

**TL;DR** The cell phone is supposed (Not owner of game so again guessing) to establish a private chat between the two of you without the need of xbox or sony menus to initiate a chat and just as a way of making it seem real they charge you from your ingame account.

Comment: Anyone want to explain the downvote? Or is it because I have secondhand facts?

Comment: I didn't downvote so I don't know, but tried calling outside of being in a party and still nothing happens.  Phone rings endlessly and no chats/parties are created. Thank you though for your answer!

Comment: I meant that it should set up a private chat in game without the knowledge of Xbox's OS. You asked what happens in game, this was my explanation of what the Developers **MAY** have done to implement the feature. Unless you are asking HOW to connect to a friend in GTA V.

Comment: Sorry, without a definitive source, I cannot mark this as an accepted answer :(

Comment: @Dom Are you trying to make a call and your friends arent answering? Because that's a different thing entirely. I dont know anyone that has the game for me to borrow (they all are playing) so You'll need to test it out. What System do you have?

Comment: To reiterate, This answer is explaining the POSSIBILITIES of what goes on under the hood of GTA V. NOT 100% TRUTHS. I don't work for rockstar so I don't know how it all works but rather based on Past Xbox 360 Knowledge this is what devs have done in the past to establish private chats.

Comment: For myself, I have gotten this feature to work multiple times. Usually it is just about the fact that the other guy doesn't notice your call. For example you can set your phone to mute. maybe the whole thing goes through rockstars servers as it seems separate from the consoles VoIP features.